# ggplot2’s mpg dataset – how to understand the geom_point graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

Why does this graph not show overlaps

Some of the cars in this dataset share the same combination for x and y (displ and hwy).

- For example for displ = 2 and hwy = 29, there are: 1 midsize; 6 compact and 3 subcompact.

However, in this spot there is only a green dot showing only 1 midsize. What am I misunderstanding about this graph?

Thank you so much!

```
ggplot(data = mpg) + 
geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy, color = class))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from jitter, you can also change the alpha argument in geom_point() to 0.3 or 0.4, by default it is 1, which means 100% opaque.

```
ggplot(data = mpg) +
geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy, color = class, alpha = 0.3))
```

This will highlight areas of over-plotting

Answer (score 2):

Carsten,

The call to [goem_point()](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_point.html) will map coordinates over each other, hence you will see only one point, this is especially true for small datasets. You can address this by using [geom_jitter()](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_jitter.html), which allows you to insert noise into the plot allowing you to see all points.

### Solution: geom_jitter()

Here we use [geom_jitter()](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_jitter.html), to insert noise into the plot data allowing us to see all overlapping points.

```
if (require(ggplot2) ) install.packages("ggplot2")
data(mtcars)
ggplot(data = mpg) + 
  geom_jitter(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy, color = class))
```

#### Plot Output: (Points slightly shifted to distinguish each point)

Note how the inserted "noise" allows you to distinguish the plot points.

[image]

nb. The jitter geom is a convenient shortcut for geom_point(position = "jitter"). It adds a small amount of random variation to the location of each point, and is a useful way of handling overplotting caused by discreteness in smaller datasets.

Answer (score 0):

The geom_jitter solution and alpha changing solution are both excellent.  A third possibility is to map the size of the marker to the number of observations at those coordinates (along with an alpha adjustment) using [geom_count()](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_count.html):

```
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)
ggplot(data = mpg) + 
    geom_count(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy, color = class), alpha = .5)
```

Comment: thank you all three so much - I see, I need to do some basic ggplot2 work before asking these straight forward issues - the ggplot cheat sheet might be a good start to get an overview. Thanks again